# How to configure netbeans php project so as not to copy all files to var/www

Tags: php, netbeans

I started using netbeans IDE for writing in php.
It is possible to make that netbeans copy project files to var/www directory?
How to configure netbeans so that not all files are copied to var/www ?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy source files by right Click your project -> Go to Properties -> Go to source tab -> Tick the copy files from source folder to another folder -> Give the path to var/www.

I don't know any other direct method to do that, but you can add your project to any version control(SVN) and then you can select from Netbeans which files you want to commit (Even the nbproject folder).